# Squirrel can not find an informix drivers

Tags: informix, squirrel-sql

This is my first question in this program, but I really can't find a drivers for squirrel SQL client. When I try to connect to INFORMIX I get error like this

> "Could not find class com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver in neither the Java
>   class path nor the Extra class path of the Informix_EUROAT driver
>   definition: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"

Can you guys help my to find these drivers?

Answer (score 2):

You can download the latest Informix JDBC driver (4.10.JC12)  directly from the maven repository:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.informix/jdbc/4.10.12

Just put the 'ifxjdbc.jar' file in your squirrel lib directory or CLASSPATH and it should work as it's already trying to load the driver (com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver)